# Intuition behind Method of Moments estimators of Binomial distribution

Tags: probability, binomial-distribution, moments, point-estimation, method-of-moments

The method of moments estimators of the binomial distributions ($x \sim Binom(n, p)$) are a bit weird... I got $\hat p = \bar x + 1 - \frac{\sum x_i^2}{\sum x_i}$ and $\hat n = \frac{\bar x}{\hat p}$.

Is there any intuition behind this? The 2nd part is reasonable, as the restriction of $x = np$ has to hold. But what is this weird estimation for $p$ itself?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For a binomial RV, we have $\operatorname{var}(X)=np(1-p)$, $E[X]=np$. To estimate $p$, we need to get rid of $n$. If you take the ratio:

$${\operatorname{var}(X) \over E[X]}=1-p$$

Put $E[X]\approx \bar{x}$, and $\operatorname{var}(X)\approx \frac{1}{n}\sum x_i^2 - \frac{1}{n}\bar{x}^2$:
$$p\approx1-\frac{\sum x_i^2}{n\bar{x}}+\bar{x}=1+\bar{x}-\frac{\sum x_i^2}{\sum x_i}$$

Not a perfect intuition, but at least you know how the weird expression is derived.

Comment: The OPs question suggests they had derived it themselves